# Socket Server in Windows Service

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-services

I have service application which deploys several windows services

```
static void Main()
        {
            DebugManager manager = new DebugManager();

            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1(),
                new Service2(),
                new Service3(),
                            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
```

Here is DebugManager

```
public class DebugManager : BaseDebug
    {
        private AsyncServer s;

        public DebugManager()
        {
            s = new AsyncServer(10000);
            s.Start();
        }

        public override void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            ts.SendMessage(message);
        }

       }
```

And Socket Server itself

```
class AsyncServer
    {
        private Socket _serverSocket;
        private List<Socket> _clients;

        private int _port;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[255];

        public AsyncServer(int port) { _port = port; }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                _clients = new List<Socket>();
                SetupServerSocket();
                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), _serverSocket);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void SetupServerSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry localMachineInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                IPEndPoint myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localMachineInfo.AddressList[1], _port);
                _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
                _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket s = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
                Socket socket = s.EndAccept(result);
                _clients.Add(socket);

                _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), result.AsyncState);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

       public void SendMessage(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] bits = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
                SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
                args.SetBuffer(bits, 0, bits.Length);

                foreach (var client in _clients)
                {
                    if (!client.Connected)
                    {
                        _clients.Remove(client);
                        continue;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        client.SendAsync(args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

When I deploy my service it seems that my socket server is not starting or is started and then closed immediatly. Is there any problem in my design or may be im code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found out the problem. It was

```
private void SetupServerSocket()
        {
            try
            {
                IPHostEntry localMachineInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
                //Here is problem 
                IPEndPoint myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(localMachineInfo.AddressList[1], _port);
                _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
                _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLogManager.LogInformation(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Several adresses are returned and [1] was IPV6. Changed it to InterNetwork and it worked. I think it worked before but my client couldn`t connect to server.