# How to access the property of windows service from application

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

I have a windows service which contains a property of return type `DataTable`

```
public partial class ServiceForCount : ServiceBase
{
    public DataTable AllData
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ServiceForCount()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int sizeOfFile)
    {
        //base.OnCustomCommand(command);
    }
}
```

If I want to call events from my application I can call like

```
   ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("ServiceForCount");
  sc.ExecuteCommand(size);
```

I want to get the `DataTable` into my application. How can I do it.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that with `ServiceController.ExecuteCommand`. It is one way only and its purpose is not that anyway.

You could do it by hosting a web service in the windows service (WCF self hosted, WebApi OWIN self hosted) or with remoting. All the web service needs to expose is a method that returns not the datatable but as list of objects. So you need to convert the DataTable to an `IEnumerable<DataObject>` where `DataObject` is your service contract.

You could look into these for starters:

1. [WebApi 2 Self Hosted Web Services](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api).
2. [How to host a WCF Service in a managed application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

To communicate with a Windows Service the service needs to provide an endpoint.

The service could open a socket and start listening for incoming messages/requests. As a response the service could serialize the data table (or any other object) and pass it back.

See: [Socket Server in Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570309/socket-server-in-windows-service)

As for the protocol: you could serialize data using standard Xml serialization or JSON. For the commands you could implement a REST API or SOAP API. Just be careful not to re-implement WCF; if you need all the features of WCF just use it.

Comment: any reference links please ??

Comment: @Iam - I added a link to a socket listener. Please try and build it and ask specific question you have.